# BSONDecoder doesn't understand type : 53 Excpetion

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, bson

It's hard to tell how it happens. I use mongodb for hadoop output (com.mongodb.hadoop). It seems all right in the beginning. When I tried to do a modification on the data, this issue just burst out.I cannot read the output collection data from both umongo(https://github.com/agirbal/umongo) & mongoHub(http://mongohub.todayclose.com/). I even cannot solve it by roll back my code.

Here is the trace from umongo

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: BSONDecoder doesn't understand type : 53 name: S
    at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder.decodeElement(BasicBSONDecoder.java:226)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder.decodeElement(BasicBSONDecoder.java:206)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder._decode(BasicBSONDecoder.java:79)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder.decode(BasicBSONDecoder.java:57)
    at com.mongodb.DefaultDBDecoder.decode(DefaultDBDecoder.java:56)
    at com.mongodb.Response.<init>(Response.java:66)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:128)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.call(DBPort.java:79)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:218)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:305)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._check(DBCursor.java:369)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor.getServerAddress(DBCursor.java:687)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor.toString(DBCursor.java:740)
    at com.edgytech.umongo.CollectionPanel$4.getRoot(CollectionPanel.java:427)
    at com.edgytech.umongo.DbJob.wrapUp(DbJob.java:130)
    at com.edgytech.umongo.DbJob$1.done(DbJob.java:81)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$5.run(SwingWorker.java:717)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$DoSubmitAccumulativeRunnable.run(SwingWorker.java:814)
    at sun.swing.AccumulativeRunnable.run(AccumulativeRunnable.java:95)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$DoSubmitAccumulativeRunnable.actionPerformed(SwingWorker.java:824)
    at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Timer.java:291)
    at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Timer.java:221)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:643)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:641)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:652)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

MongoDB: mongodb-2.2.0-x86_64 from HomeBrew(http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/)

OS: Mac OS 10.8.1

Driver: 2.7.2 & 2.7.3

**UPDATE**

The error from mongo shell

```
Wed Sep 26 09:24:20 Assertion: 10320:BSONElement: bad type 53
0x10004656b 0x1000b9b1e 0x100013a62 0x100292425 0x10011ef2e 0x100120ec8 0x10014ab74 0x1001498f4 0x1001cd414 0x1001490fc 0x10014ad81 0x100159c8f 0x100255418 0x10025551b 0x10029d0ba 0x100007277 0x10000919a 0x100000dd4 0x1 
 0   mongo                               0x000000010004656b _ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo + 43
 1   mongo                               0x00000001000b9b1e _ZN5mongo11msgassertedEiPKc + 206
 2   mongo                               0x0000000100013a62 _ZNK5mongo11BSONElement4sizeEv + 418
 3   mongo                               0x0000000100292425 _ZN5mongo16resolveBSONFieldEP9JSContextP8JSObjectljPS3_ + 389
 4   mongo                               0x000000010011ef2e js_LookupPropertyWithFlags + 734
 5   mongo                               0x0000000100120ec8 js_GetProperty + 136
 6   mongo                               0x000000010014ab74 js_Interpret + 3396
 7   mongo                               0x00000001001498f4 js_Invoke + 3300
 8   mongo                               0x00000001001cd414 fun_apply + 532
 9   mongo                               0x00000001001490fc js_Invoke + 1260
 10  mongo                               0x000000010014ad81 js_Interpret + 3921
 11  mongo                               0x0000000100159c8f js_Execute + 1103
 12  mongo                               0x0000000100255418 JS_EvaluateUCScriptForPrincipals + 168
 13  mongo                               0x000000010025551b JS_EvaluateScript + 107
 14  mongo                               0x000000010029d0ba _ZN5mongo7SMScope4execERKNS_10StringDataERKSsbbbi + 330
 15  mongo                               0x0000000100007277 _Z5_mainiPPc + 12599
 16  mongo                               0x000000010000919a main + 42
 17  mongo                               0x0000000100000dd4 start + 52
 18  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
Error: BSONElement: bad type 53
```

Comment: What happens if you use mongo shell to look at the data?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I got one,check the update

Comment: could you include the whole error (and the whole command you ran)?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky nothing special, just a simple query such as `db.recommedKeywords.find()`. It was fine at first, when I use `it` for more, the error appears with some of the result before the error message.

Comment: Also getting this. Any ideas?  db.myCollection.find(query)

Comment: @Brett Infinity numbers?

Comment: @Shisoft - can't remember, it was a long time ago, but was getting the type 53 error - we had an unstable volume that causes some corruption.